# Issue on running binance api

Tags: python, api, binance

I want to get klines data from binance and make it on excel. But there are error occur.
Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd

from binance.client import Client

api_key = 'my api key'
api_secret = 'my api key'
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
klines = client.get_historical_klines('BTCUSDT', Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1MINUTE, '28 MAY, 2021')
whole_df = pd.DataFrame(klines)
whole_df.columns = ['Open_time','open','high','low','close','volume','Close_time', 'Quote asset volume', 'number of trades', 'Taker buy base asset volume', 'Taker buy quote asset volume', 'Ignore']
whole_df = whole_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Open_time'], keep=False)
whole_df = whole_df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

whole_df.to_csv('binance_BTCUSDT_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')

exit()

and the error is 

    File "C:/Users/y/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    whole_df = whole_df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    File "C:\Users\y\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5465, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'convert_objects'
```

Comment: What’s unclear about the error you’re seeing?

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects` is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) since pandas v.0.21.0.

Try using `pandas.to_numeric` instead. For example:

---

Setup:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': ['1', '2.01', 3],
    'B': ['1', '2.01', 3],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.info()
```

Console:

```
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   A       3 non-null      object
 1   B       3 non-null      object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```

Apply [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas-to-numeric):

```py
series_numeric = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], downcast='float')
print(series_numeric)
```

Output:

```
0    1.00
1    2.01
2    3.00
Name: A, dtype: float32
```

---

Concerning your binance question: I think it is not necessary to transform the kine data to `float` or `numeric`. It should already be in `dtype='float'`. If you are not sure, try `whole_df.info()` on your example and check the dtypes.